# Android TabsAdapter handle fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I want to handle one fragment within tabsadapter which is a static class in my Activity. The problem is how can i get the [getfragmentbytag](/questions/tagged/getfragmentbytag) in the onTabSelected?

From the onCreate i have this code:

```
Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("ABOUT");
tabsAdapter.addTab(tab1, PoiAboutFragment.class, null);
```

and my tabs adapter class is the following which works with no problem.

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private Object gridTag;

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager,
            ActionBar actionBar) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = actionBar;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        if(clss.equals(GridFragment.class))
            gridTag = tab.getTag();
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        Log.i(TAG, "onTabSelected has been called");
        if(tag.equals(gridTag))
            Log.i(TAG, "gridtab has been called");
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that i want to handle one of my fragments in both the oncreate method and in the tabsAdapter but i don't have neither a fragment tag neither an fragment Id. How can i handle their methods from my Activity?

Answer (score 1):

The [FragmentPagerAdapter source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java)'s `makeFragmentName` methods shows that fragments are created with the following tags:

```
"android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id
```

Where viewId is the id of the ViewPager, i.e., use

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                "android:switcher:" + pager.getId() + ":0"
```

to get the first Fragment.

Comment: ok i will test it and i will accept your answer if it works!As for the onCreate method of my activity class?How can i call a fragment from there?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for in this site [android-er.blogasppot](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html)